# What does error 'identifier must be declared' means in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

The task is to write PL/SQL block for entering new employee throw the Oracle database user's dialog to insert data into the table. I dont really understand what I am missing here:

Image

[image: 1]

```
create table Account_Information
(
id  INT Not Null,
Br_Name varchar2(20),
H_Name varchar2(20),
Address varchar2(20),
Phn varchar2(20),
Nid varchar2(20),
Blnc number(20),
primary key(id)
);


insert into Account_Information values(1,'dhaka','Rahim',  'tejgaon','01729523456','1233224',5000);
insert into Account_Information values(2,'rajshahi','karim',  'modhubagh','0172923456','1237624',8000);
insert into Account_Information values(3,'dhaka','bashir',  'dhanmondi','01729523566','1237654',9000);
insert into Account_Information values(4,'barishal','Ratul',  'jatrabri','01729345456','1274564',4000);
insert into Account_Information values(5,'rangpur','jashim',  'fakirapul','01729523232','1238799',10000);


set serveroutput on;
set verify off;
declare
        Id Account_Information.ID%TYPE := &id;
    BranchName Account_Information.BR_NAME%TYPE  := &branchname;
    AccountHolderName Account_Information.H_NAME%TYPE := &account_holder_name;
    Address Account_Information.ADDRESS%TYPE := &address;
    Contact Account_Information.PHN%TYPE := &contact;
    Nid Account_Information.NID%TYPE := &nid;
    Balance Account_Information.BLNC%TYPE := &initial_balance;
begin
    bank.open_account(Id,BranchName,AccountHolderName,Address,Contact,Nid,Balance);
    
end;

set verify off;
declare 
    AccountId Account_Information.Id%TYPE := &accountnumber;
    Amount Account_Information.BLNC%TYPE := &amount;
begin 
    bank.deposit_money(AccountId,Amount);
end;

set verify off;
declare 
    AccountId Account_Information.Id%TYPE := &accountnumber;
    Amount Account_Information.BLNC%TYPE := &amount;
begin 
    bank.withdraw_money(AccountId,Amount);
end;
set verify off;
declare
    AccountId1 Account_Information.Id%TYPE := &accountnumber;
    AccountId2 Account_Information.Id%TYPE := &accountnumber;
    Amount Account_Information.BLNC%TYPE := &amount;
begin 
    bank.transfer_money(AccountId1,AccountId2,Amount);
end;
```

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 12:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ACCOUNT_INFORMATION.ID' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 0, column 1:
PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

i am a beginner in database and i am getting the above error. I have tried several different ways to no avail

Comment: I removed the Microsoft SQL Server tag as it's not relevant to you question.

Comment: Did you actually create the table; or did you have all those statements in a worksheet and did ‘run statement’ while the cursor happened to be in an amount block, rather than ‘run script’?

Comment: In SQL Developer, you'd rather terminate PL/SQL blocks with a slash. Try to do that and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, yo do need to add a slash after each block; and then run as a script…

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code. Best way to avoid confusion is to set and/or obey some rules and stay strict. For instance:

1. table names and column names - all capital letters
2. variables - all small letters or just first letter capital or some combination
3. input parameters - & + exactly the same syntax as variable
4. put slash / after every pl/sql block to run it
5. if you are entering input params using SQL Developer's window (Enter Substitution Variable) and you are entering the VarChar2 value - enclose it with single quotes:

Here is a reduced part of your code that works by the rules above. You can set them differently if you wish so - just be consistent:

```sql
create table A_TBL
(
    ID  INT Not Null,
    BR_NAME varchar2(20),
    primary key(ID)
);

insert into A_TBL values (1, 'dhaka');
insert into A_TBL values (2, 'rajshahi');

set serveroutput on;

declare
    my_id A_TBL.ID%TYPE := &my_id;
    my_br_name A_TBL.BR_NAME%TYPE  := &my_br_name;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(my_id || '-' || my_br_name);
end;
/     -- this slash is needed

/*  R e s u l t   -->  input for &my_id was 1    -- input for &my_br_name was 'A'  (with single quotes)
table A_TBL created.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
anonymous block completed
1-A
*/
```

This way you will always know what is a column in a table and what is variable or parameter and the code would be easier to read and maintain.